# Lotus Notes HTML and Tables: How can I make this work

Tags: html, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to create a newsletter style HTML email for users who are using IBM Lotus Notes 9.0.1.

I get closed, but can't exactly get it right.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scoular Weekly Technology Newsletter</title>
</head>
<script>
</script>
<body bgcolor="#E0DED8" style="padding-top:30px;" height="1000px">
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="800px" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>    
                <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="20" border="0" width="640" align="center">
                    <tr width="650px">
                        <td bgcolor="#D7D3C7" style="padding:10px" align="center"><img alt="Scoular_HTML2" height="93" width="400px" src="" style="padding:20px"></td>
                    </tr>          
                </table>

                     <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="20" border="0" width="640" align="center">
                    <tr width="650px">
                        <td bgcolor="#D7D3C7" style="padding:10px" align="left">
                        <span> Weekly Technology Tips</span> 

                        <td bgcolor="#D7D3C7" style="padding:10px" align="right">
                            <span>IT Help Desk</span</td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                    
                </table>            
                   <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="20" border="0" width="640" align="center">
                    <tr width="650px">
                        <td bgcolor="#D7D3C7" style="padding:10px" align="center">TIP</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                  <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="20" border="0" width="640" align="center">
                    <tr width="650px">
                        <td bgcolor="#D7D3C7" style="padding:10px" align="center">TIP</td>                    </tr>
                </table>
                        <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="20" border="0" width="640" align="center">
                    <tr width="650px">
                      <td bgcolor="#D7D3C7" style="padding:10px" align="center">TIP</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                                   <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="20" border="0" width="640" align="center">
                    <tr width="650px">
                        <td bgcolor="#D7D3C7" style="padding:10px" align="center">FOOTER</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

In any web tool it looks like this, which is generally how I want to it to look.:

[image]

However when I send it to Lotus Notes (I am using the testing tool [PutsMail](http://putsmail.com) to send jt to my Lotus Notes email account, here is what I get. I know it looks almost the same, but it is not.There is extra space on the left.

I have struggled for hours trying to figure out what is wrong.

Can anyone see something that I am missing.

[image]

Comment: Only use 1 table for the entire thing.

Comment: I am trying to do it this way,but still struggling. Do have any code you can get me started with?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/upa0unek/

Comment: I have that part, Nicholas, what breaks is when I try to put in the padding. I can get it to look like what it looks like on the bottom picture, but the width of the white column on the left does not match the width of the space on the column on the right. In addition, the space to the left of the text entries is greater than the space on the right. It works in other email clients, but NOT in Lotus Notes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/upa0unek/4/

Comment: If you view it in different browsers what do you get? Notes9 is built on Firefox10ESR, while Notes8.x is FF3.5 I would be interested in seeing if its a browser problem or Notes.